# PostGIS: Export a buffer with shp2pgsql

Tags: postgis, shp2pgsql

I want to create a buffer around a line:

```
SELECT ST_Buffer(wkb_geometry, 50, 'endcap=flat join=round') FROM linien WHERE route = 'Rundweg'
```

and export it with shp2pgsql:

```
pgsql2shp -f <path to output shapefile> -h <hostname> -u <username> -P <password> databasename "SELECT ST_Buffer(wkb_geometry, 50, 'endcap=flat join=round') FROM linien WHERE route = 'Rundweg'"

Initializing... 
Done (postgis major version: 3).
Output shape: Polygon
Dumping: X [1 rows].
```

But sadly, I'll get a layer with an empty attribute table / no feature in QGIS.
When I do the same with another query, it works fine. So my query must be the problem.

How do I export a line buffer with shp2pgsql?

Comment: Your select contains only the buffered geometry. Select the attributes as well.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem.